# Intel Graphics Driver for Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: upgrade, intel-graphics

I need to install the Graphics Driver in my Ubuntu 16.10 but when I try to install the Intel Graphics updater I get:

> This package is uninstallable
>
> Dependency is not satisfiable: `libpackagekit-glib2-16`.

Comment: You don't need.

Comment: Newer Intel Graphics drivers usually come out **months** after a new Ubuntu release. So, you're gonna have to wait for a while. The Intel drivers are buggy anyway, and are difficult to roll back. Cheers, Al

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 8):

I fiddled around until I got it working, here's what I think the actual steps you need to do to get the existing intel graphics driver working with 16.10 are:

1. Download The deb for libpackagekit-glib2-16 here - http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libpackagekit-glib2-16/download and install that deb using dpkg -i.
2. Download and install the intel-linux-graphics-installer using dpkg -i. Currently it's version 1.4.0: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads
3. Copy /etc/lsb-release to /etc/lsb-release.backup.

   `$ sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.backup`
4. Modify /etc/lsb-release to what it was for xenial:

   `DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
   DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
   DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04"`
5. Fetch and accept the public key used by the current intel repo:

   `$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 56A3DEF863961D39`
6. Run the intel linux graphics installer:

   `$ sudo intel-linux-graphics-installer`
7. Restore you original `/etc/lsb-release` file:

   `$ mv /etc/lsb-release.backup /etc/lsb-release`

After that, it'll prompt you to reboot. After the reboot I'm running using the intel drivers.

Comment: This should work fine, just pay attention while you do it, and maybe make sure your terminal keeps its history. This way if something happens and you get stuck in some kind of package/repo conflict black hole you can find your way back. But if that happens it was your fault not khamer's, I did the same as listed above and works fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Intel Graphics Installer 2.0.3 Now Supports Ubuntu 16.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/11/intel-graphics-installer-support-for-ubuntu-16-10)

including:

- Atomic watermark update support for Ironlake to Broadwell
- Color management improvements
- Fixes for DiRT Showdown and Bioshock on Broadwell devices
- MESA 12.0.1
- Xorg Xserver v1.18.3
- Vulkan improvements

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall of Intel® Graphics for Linux 2.0.3 to a 16.10 @ skylake.

See the original link below to original post, i just forked this to fit 16.10,
https://theclonker.de/removing-the-intel-linux-graphics-driver/

Open a new Terminal (CTRL+Alt+T) and make a new file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal
```

Paste this code in the File and save it

```
    Package: *
    Pin: release a=yakkety*
    Pin-Priority: 1001

    Package: *
    Pin: origin download.01.org
    Pin-Priority: -100
```

Then run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(this will install back the packages you had originally)

Then just some cleaning in terminal

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/intel-removal
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/intellinuxgraphics.list*
sudo apt-get update
```

Don’t forget to remove the actual Drivers !

```
sudo apt-get purge i965-3.6-3.5-dkms intel-linux-graphics-installer
```

reboot and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Its because Ubuntu 16.10 is not using libpackagekit-glib2-16 its using libpackagekit-glib2-18 then the installer cannot find the package "libpackagekit-glib2-16" and give this error i have the same problem i think best is to wait for release for Ubuntu 16.10 or hard way and get sources from Ubuntu 16.04 and download libpackagekit-glib2-16 using `sudo apt-get install libpackagekit-glib2-16` but best is to wait for 16.10 drivers release because you never know if libpackagekit-glib2-16 will work on 16.10

Comment: Not a solution and there are no newer drivers to install anyway.

Comment: i know that its not solution but i said its best to wait for newer drivers for ubuntu 16.10

Comment: What problem? Intel drivers are open-source, included by default and updated when deemed convenient in the kernel. That tool merely adds a PPA with slightly newer drivers. For the vast majority of users there's absolutely nothing to gain from a minor revision. That's why I commented above: *You don't need* and neither do you.

Comment: i already know that but if you want the newest drivers then you cannot since this litlle package thats sad

Answer (score 0):

You can get the dependency you need from here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/libpackagekit-glib2-18/download

then install it with either dpkg -i or gdebi package installer :) Don't forget to run with sudo intel-graphics-update-tool

Comment: Why not add some more information, like steps with both options.

Comment: It should run flawlessly without problems while you run it, the only problem that may occur during installation is that if your dependencies or other apt installer related error does pop up your intel gr installer will take it as it's self error.