# Ubuntu 16.10 booting in emergency mode after upgrade from 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.10

Ubuntu 16.10 on my Lenovo G500 is booting in emergency mode after upgrade from 16.04. The previous upgrades worked just fine (14.04 to 15.04 to 15.10 and so on).

### Things I already tried:

1. Attempt 1:

   - Booted using Live Ubuntu 16.04 DVD.
   - Started a terminal and did a file check on the my root partition i.e:  `e2fsck -pvf /dev/sda9`
   - Rebooted from HDD

Result: Booted in emergency mode

2. Attempt 2

   - Booted from Live Ubuntu 16.04 DVD
   - Did a `tune2fs -l /dev/sda9 | grep -i check`, turned out `fsck` was last performed in July 2016.
   - Mounted `/dev/sda9` and created a file `forcefsck` in `/´ directory
   - Rebooted from HDD.

Result: Booted in emergency mode.

After rebooting the screen looks like this:

[image]

Tune2fs results look like this:

[image: Tune2fs results]

I am out of ideas.

### Update

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.10, with the contents in my `$HOME` directory intact. But I still do not know the exact reason, why it failed to boot.

Comment: Did you install that nasty Intel Video Driver for 16.04? You should be able to `ppa-purge` it, or install the 16.10 version of the driver. Ask if you need more info/help.

Comment: @heynnema I did not install it explicitly but may be while upgrading it was done automatically I'm guessing. I just checked, is it the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver you mean?

Comment: You would have had to explicitly installed the Intel Video driver at some point. The 16.10 upgrade wouldn't have done it. In your GRUB menu, go into edit mode and find the kernel/linux line that contains "splash quiet" and edit it so it says "splash quiet nomodeset" and see if you can boot fully.

Comment: You could also see if you can find if the Intel driver has been installed by `dpkg -l *intel* | grep ii` and see if you find it.

Comment: Yea i did a `dpkg --list | grep intel` previously to find that driver i mentioned, I found the line that says `quiet splash $vt_handoff`. Should I replace `$vt_handoff` with `nomodeset`. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: No, xserver-xorg-video-intel is not what we're looking for. Yes, the "quiet splash $vt_handoff" line is where you want to add nomodeset. Keep this URL for future reference... http://askubuntu.com/questions/838296/intel-graphics-driver-for-ubuntu-16-10

Comment: Show me `dpkg -l *i965* | grep ii`

Comment: here is the link (http://imgur.com/a/yrxcP). Additionally i added a nomodeset but it failed to even boot.

Comment: Good news is that it appears that you don't have the Intel Video driver installed. However, the errors that you're getting at boot time indicate a video/video driver problem. Try nomodeset once more, but this time replace the $vt_handoff with it, and see what happens. Otherwise you may just have to do a 16.10 reinstall using a Ubuntu Live DVD 16.10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54369/discussion-between-abel-tom-and-heynnema).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/840496/startup-error-uncleared-pch-fifo-underrun-on-pch-transcoder, this worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a simple permanent solution. This worked for me on 16.04.2 LTS:

1. In your GRUB menu, go into edit mode and find the kernel/linux line that contains `"splash quiet"` and replace `$vt_handoff` with `nomodeset`. You should now be able to boot properly.
2. Edit the file `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`.
   Find the `vt_handoff` variable, around line 27 and change
   `vt_handoff="1"` to `vt_handoff="0"`
   and save the file.
3. Finally:

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot

Comment: I had the same issue and your solution worked like a charm